# JavaScript not working in Ruby on Rails app

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, mobile

I want to make a collapisible side menu with JS and CSS for my app. Here is my code:

In views/pages/home.html.erb I have:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= csp_meta_tag %>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application','data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

<div class = "head">
    
    <div class = "navbar">
        <div id="mySidepanel" class="sidepanel">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <a href="#">Services</a>
            <a href="#">Clients</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
        <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Toggle Sidepanel</button>

        <h1 class = "titles">
            <%if current_user%>
                ¡Bienvenido <%=current_user.first_name%>!
            <%else%>
                Home
            <%end%>
        </h1>

        <h3 class = "secondary-contact">25 de mayo 1160 Puiggari, Entre Rios, Argentina</h3>
        <h3 class = "secondary-contact">TEL. 0343 15-467-5058</h3>
    </div>
```

My stylesheets/application.css

```
.sidepanel {
    height: 250px; /* Specify a height */
    width: 0; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111; /* Black*/
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
    padding-top: 60px; /* Place content 60px from the top */
    transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidepanel */
  }
  
  /* The sidepanel links */
  .sidepanel a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  
  /* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
  .sidepanel a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
  }
  
  /* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */
  .sidepanel .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
  
  /* Style the button that is used to open the sidepanel */
  .openbtn {
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #111;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border: none;
  }
  
  .openbtn:hover {
    background-color: #444;
  }
```

In javascript/packs/application.js I added:

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("x").style.width = "15%";
  }
  
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidepanel").style.width = "0";
  }
```

The problem is that when I click the button nothing happens. I'm very new with JavaScript and I can´t find my error.

Comment: I'd try to console.log in those functions to see if they are called. Do u know how to check the console in your browser?

Comment: I could make it work but only if i put the JS code in my html file between <script> </script>. Obviously I prefer to have my JS code in my application.js, because of organization. No, I don´t know how to check the console, I´d appreciate if you tell me how, thanks!

Comment: Depends on your browser, but usually right click -> inspect and then there's a console tab https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/ . See if you see any javascript errors in the console when you click on your links. Btw where is the element with id = "x"?  document.getElementById("x")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not access directly application.js or other js file functions  from  dom. Because rails use webpack for your codes. You can use events like this;

```
let openButton = document.querySelectorAll('button.openbtn')
openButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  document.getElementById("x").style.width = "15%";
})

let closeButton = document.querySelectorAll('button.closebtn')
closeButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  document.getElementById("mySidepanel").style.width = "0";
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Muhammet's answer is right:

- When using Webpacker, all the functions are private and not visible to the DOM
- Either use Muhammet's solution of binding events in Webpack (preferred), or:
- export the functions to the global scope:

```js
window.openNav = function() {
 document.getElementById("x").style.width = "15%";
}
```